# Capacitors - аffected by temperature or not?

Tags: capacitor, temperature, stable

Are these capacitors аffected by the temperature changing or not?
http://www.cde.com/resources/catalogs/TAS.pdf

Comment: Did you see the "Reverse Voltage", "DC Leakage", and "∆ Capacitance Maximum" sections on the first page of the datasheet?

Comment: It says that its temperature stable. Does this mean somehow that the temperature doesn't affect the capacitors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It says that its temperature stable. Does this mean somehow that the temperature doesn't affect the capacitors?

### No.

It means that temperature affects it a lot *less* than most capacitors. It's just marketing speak. In actuality it's capacitance will change less than about 10% over it's full temperature range (which is very good for an industrial range capacitor by the way).

Answer (score 0):

According to the datasheet, the maximum change in capacitance from room temperature is -10% at -55C and +12% at 125C.  This is good but hardly temperature stable.